# Can my iOS app use a compilation condition defined in a SPM module

Tags: ios, swift, swift-package-manager

I'm defining a compilation condition in a SPM module that is being used by my iOS app. I'd like to be able to use the same compilation condition in my app code to determine behavior, but the condition doesn't seem to be getting set within my app. The condition is working as expected within the SPM module, just not in the iOS app that is importing the module.

#### Package.swift excerpt

```
target(..., 
swiftSettings: [.define("CONDITION", .when(configuration: .debug))]
)
```

#### SPM Module

```
#if CONDITION
// Compiled and executes as expected
#endif
```

#### App

```
#if CONDITION
// Never compiled / triggered
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

A specific SwiftSetting (aka "compiler directive"), for example your `CONDITION` directive, which is defined for a specific target within a Swift Package is not defined in the app target or in other targets in the same package or in other packages.

You may define a custom build setting for your app target in Xcode, that is derived from the Build Configuration in the same way, though.

However, it doesn't seem a to be a good idea to let the app depend on some target's build settings. This will break sooner or later.

See also Xcode documentation:
[Configuring the build settings of a target](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/configuring-the-build-settings-of-a-target)